# JavaScript Array.sort doesn't work on some arrays of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to use JavaScript's sort function on arrays of numbers and sometimes it doesn't do anything:

```
var a = [200,20].sort(); // [20,200]
var b = [200,21].sort(); // [200,21]
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NRLN/1/)

Comment: Because that is already sorted?

Comment: @putvande shouldn't [200,21] become [21, 200]?

Comment: This was easily googleable.

Comment: When a method doesn't work the way you'd expect, step 1 is to read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: I didn't even suspect that js would sort everything alphanumerically. I was certain that I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript sorts everything as strings (=alphabetically) by default. The string `"200"` is less than the string `"21"`. To sort as numbers you have to tell it so:

```
[200,21].sort(function(a,b) { return  a-b })
```

Comment: This code can be shortened using an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). `numberArray.sort((a, b) => (a - b));` Yay!  **Note: check if your JS engine supports Arrow Functions.**

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is the standard behaviour for "sort" because it perform "string" reordering. If you want to sort by number value you must pass a "compare" function to sort, like this:

```
[200,21].sort(function (a, b) {
  return a-b; 
})
// [21, 200]
```

The function must return 0 for identical value, n < 0 if a < b and n > 0 if a > b. For that reason, the difference is enough to provide sorting (assuming that you're not using huge numbers)