# Javascript sort() with concat()

Tags: javascript, sorting, concatenation

Why doesn't this sort in numeric order after concat?

```
var hege = [34, 12];
var stale = [1, 78, 8, 4];
var children = hege.concat(stale).sort(); //1,12,34,4,78,8
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kN5H/

Comment: "The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points." -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: so how should I sort numerically?

Comment: Thanks for the -1.  My bad for thinking sort could possibly due that.  I'm sure no one else ever made that mistake.

Comment: That's the point, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/arr-sort-does-not-sort-integers-correctly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093874/why-doesnt-the-sort-function-of-javascript-work-well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989665/javascript-array-sort-doesnt-work-on-some-arrays-of-numbers, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `.sort` method sorts elements alphabetically

use

```
.sort(function(a,b){return a - b})
```

---

```
var children = hege.concat(stale).sort(function(a,b){return a - b}); //1,4,8,12,34,78
```

**[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kN5H/1/)**

Comment: Is there a way to sort numerically?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
hege.concat(stale).sort(function(a,b){return (+a)-(+b)})
```

Here we are converting each value in number & sorting as numbers.

Because by default javascript sort does ordering as string, you have to specify how you want to sort.

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunction() {
    var hege = [34, 12];
    var stale = [1, 78, 8, 4];
    var children = hege.concat(stale).sort((hege, stale) => hege>stale); 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= children;
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: This produces the output 34,12,1,78,8,4